# AWS Model - JSON string inside string type

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, model, aws-api-gateway

What I'm trying to do is to have a basic model that takes in a JSON string rather than defined all my variables/elements upfront.  My model will take in an "options" element which I want to contain a json string.  My model is below.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "GroceryStoreInputModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "options":{"type":"string"}
  }
}
```

in my api-gateway, this will work with i just do a basic body like this:

```
{"options":"this is my options"}
```

but i get a model not matching error if I replaced the string with a json string.

```
  {"options":"{\\"name\\":\\"thaison\\",\\"mail\\":\\"test2\\"}"}
```

I also tried "" escaped but did not work as well, is there a way to do this?

```
{"options":"{""name"":""thaison"",""mail"":""test2""}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your payload value for the `options` node is being interpreted as `object` instead of `string`. Can you try the following settings instead to solve the problem?

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "GroceryStoreInputModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "options":{"type":"object"}
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this will work, object allows me to just put an actual json string without escape, it will work.  thanks